# Can't register Chrome app for GCM

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to register a chrome app to get a registration id so I test but the chrome javascript console is showing:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined

I don't know what's wrong. I got the example from: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples#push-messaging

Answer (score 1):

Seems your Chrome APIs are not loaded.

You need to make sure your Chrome APIs are loaded in order to use the push messaging methods.

In order to load the Chrome APIs correctly, follow [the step 5 in Chrome developer page](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app) to launch your app or extension. For some newer Chrome browser, you can go to `Settings -> Extensions -> Load unpacked extension`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem,
Eventually the problem was that content scripts cannot use a lot of chrome.* APIs.

GCM is one of them.

[Source](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)